# navigation.dispatch is undefined in reactnavigation

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

Im creating a react-native app with reactnavigation and redux.

On loading the app I get the following warning from NavContainer: `Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 'navigation.dispatch' is marked as required in 'CardStack', but its value is 'undefined'`

This leads to errors when I attempt to navigate pages via `this.props.navigation.navigate('Station');` as navigation.dispatch is not a function

The app has a NavContainer which I'm guessing is missing something as dispatch is undefined in the render function:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation'
import AppNavigator from '../lib/navigationConfiguration'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { ActionCreators } from '../actions';

class NavContainer extends Component {

  render(){
    const { dispatch, navigationState} = this.props
    return (
      <AppNavigator
        navigation={
          addNavigationHelpers({
            dispatch: dispatch,
            state: navigationState
          })
        }
      />
    )
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    navigationState: state.nav
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavContainer)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you define a `mapDispatchToProps`, `connect` doesn't pass `dispatch` to the wrapped component.. that's why `this.props.dispatch` is undefined. To solve this, you could do:

```js
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return Object.assign({dispatch: dispatch}, bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch));
}
```

Comment: you don't need to pass `mapDispatchToProps`, when omit the second parameter to connect it automatically pass dispatch to props.